# In PHP how do a translate a date to numerical format not knowing the format of the string beforehand?

Tags: php, date

Examples of the translations I need to do:

```
$stringDate = "November 2009";  $output = "11/09";
$stringDate = "October 1 2010"; $output = "10/01/2010";

$stringDate = "January 2010"; $output = "01/10";
$stringDate = "January 9 2010"; $output = "01/09/2010";
```

Note that I do not know which format the $stringDate will be in and the lack of commas in the month day year set.

Thanks for any help anyone might offer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[PHP.net strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime)

First convert it to UNIX timestamp using strtotime, then to your own format using date() function.

Comment: This is the method I use, and it works well.  The second parameter of the date() function is optional, and can be any timestamp (default is, of course, the current time).

Answer (score 2):

Use [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) - it can capture the date and/or time in most formats and convert it to a timestamp which you then can format as you wish with [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

EDIT:
You can for example do it like this:

```
$stringDate = "October 1 2010";
$mysql_datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($stringDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that "November 2009" is not a date but "October 1 2010" is.

If your input type is unknown (date, date range, etc.), it´s going to be extremely difficult to get a reliable conversion.

For a date you can of course use `date("format", strtotime($input))` but that only solves part of the problem and will lead to problems if `$input` is not a date.

Comment: strtotime() returns FALSE if inputted date isn't recognized, not much of a problem though .)

Comment: @Kemo, you're kind of missing the point, the input is not a date by definition, it can be a date-range and that smells like a potential *garbage in => garbage out* problem to me.